# How to change input language in login to XRDP?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, xrdp, internationalization

I can enter my login name in RDP since it is latin. While installing Ubuntu, I set language switch to `Ctrl-Shift` and it works in console.

Here it is ignored.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem with xrdp login to an Ubuntu 18.04 VM on Hyper-V on Windows 10. It turns out that the keyboard layout of xrdp on connection is the same as the keyboard layout of the host.

So I just need to change the Windows keyboard layout to English before connection to VM.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that is can solve your problem but we have found the info on http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305

To set Keyboard layout at the xrdp Login screen, perform the following steps
As explained above, with no special configuration, the xrdp login screen keyboard layout is set to english by default.  if you need to change it to another keyboard layout, you should proceed with the following actions

This is the command you should issue in order to change the keyboard layout to be used during xrdp sessions…

Step 1 : You go to the /etc/xrdp directory

Step 2 : you issue the command setxkbmap -layout <%your layout%> to define which keyboard map/layout to use

Step 3 : create a copy of the km-0409.ini file into the same directory. It seems that this is the default file used by xrdp to define the keyboard layout. You will need to use sudo in order to be able to write into the directory

Step 4 : Check that you have a backup of your file by typing the dir or ls command

Step 5 : update the file by issuing the following command sudo xrdp-genkeymap km-0409.ini

give it a try and see if this works

See ya

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and this is how i solved it.

Just remove all km-*.ini files from /etc/xrdp exept english *0409.ini, and remove all mentions about these files from xrdp_keyboard.ini.